# How to get HyperV Notes field programmatically

Tags: c#, virtual-machine, wmi, hyper-v

I added a value to Notes field of the virtual machine with Hyper-V Manager.

How can I get the value at the Notes field programmatically?

Can I get the value with WMI classes and properties?

I tried to get the value with *Msvm_ComputerSystem* class but I could not find any property obut Notes.

Comment: You can do it with the Sev-VM Hyper-V Powershell cmdlet. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848575.aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie the problem is not about setting a value to Notes field, I want to get the value.

Comment: I figured that would be enough for you to track down where those cmdlets use "Notes"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hyper-V Powershell cmdlets [use](https://pshyperv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#VMConfig/Get-VMSettingData.ps1) the [`Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136944(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class.  In that class there is a `Notes` member that can be read.  It's read-only; but can be modified via [`ModifyVirtualSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136809(v=vs.85).aspx) method on [`Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136940(v=vs.85).aspx).